# Clarification of method notation in yeast cultivation method

Tags: literature, yeast, experimental

I'm reading a paper about yeast culture and in the methods, it says:

> Then $5$ ml of sterile $M/15\ KH_2PO_4$, was added to the slant,

What is the meaning of $M/15$?

Comment: Can you add the paper itself? or a screenshot of the relevant section?

Comment: The only interpretation I can think of is a concentration of (1/15) M, i.e. 67 mM. But I've never seen anyone write it this way.

Comment: @VictorChubukov That's what I thought, thanks

Comment: @VictorChubukov. That's what it is. I just verified. I don't know much about the history of that though but it is an old notation that is no longer used. Can you please post an answer?